# Can I search for applications compiled against X11/Xorg for MacPorts?

Tags: macports, x11

Similar to [this question on building against native xQuartz vs MacPort's Xorg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354760/can-i-tell-macports-to-build-against-its-own-x11-or-xorg), is it possible to search for just applications built against Xorg?

For example, I want to know what Web Browsers are available (if any) that I can run inside of my i3 Window Manager that I installed with Mac Ports? Is there a method to find this out (with `port`) without installing them?

Comment: https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=category&substr=x11 seems like a good place to start :-)

Comment: Cool! I'm easy, that's a totally valid answer and what I'm looking for if you want to answer it I'll mark it as chosen.

Comment: Actually that's not really good because you can either search by category (which x11 works with) but not by category and description =(

Comment: Well, that's the best that is available

Comment: @nohillside it is a tough life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to work for my purposes. It seems that it's what the web site ties into.

```
port echo category:x11 description:browser
```

`port search` is a non-starter as it doesn't seem to take the pseudo-selector syntax (which is the `category:` and description:` stuff).

Answer (score 3):

https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=category&substr=x11 seems like a good place to start :-)

Comment: I'm going to mark this as Accepted, but I'm not going anywhere and for posterity if anyone knows how to search category and description (which the web interface doesn't seem to permit) I'll jump to choosing that one. This does seem to be the best that's available for now though.

Comment: @EvanCarroll maybe try Google with the site fixed on macports.org